# How to directly connect a macbook to a device with a static ip address

Tags: networking, static-ip

I have a [device](https://www.waveshare.com/product/iot-communication/wired-comm-converter/ethernet-to-rs232-rs485/rs232-485-to-eth.htm) that serves a web interface at http://192.168.0.7 but I cannot access it because my home network uses a different subnet.

I have a macbook with an ethernet adaptor. How can I connect the macbook directly to the device so that I can access the above url? (I tried manually assigning the ip address of the Mac's ethernet interface to 192.168.0.8 but this didn't help.)

Comment: If you have control over the router & need this connection repeatedly, then change the router's network to match. What's the mystery 'device'?